# localstorage doesn't work in my angular application

Tags: javascript, json, angular, local-storage

I have a login page to my angular11 app and when i click on connexion button, i call a rest API JAVA.

I get data but i can't store my data to localstorage in my google chrome browser and also mozilla

```
login() {
    this.authService.login(this.loginForm.value).subscribe(
      res => this.handleResponse(res)
    )
  }
  
  handleResponse(data:any) {
    localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
    localStorage.setItem('id', data.id);
    localStorage.setItem('nom', data.nom);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/livres'); 
  }
```

I check if localstorage is supported by my browser

```
if (window.localStorage) {
        console.log('local storage supported !!!');
      } else {
        console.log('local storage not supported  $$$ ');
      }
```

And i get in the console local storage supported !!! but any key and value is storage to my site web

and this is my data {token: "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJte…E5OH0.8MxLhs1puaQHlA2UZ-I1lBirWtZxj0FvsJ8_uvB53DI", nom: "toto", id: "1"}

Any idea ?

Answer (score 4):

You only can set strings to localStorage or sessionStorage, so you can create an object with your data, and then JSON.stringify(tokenData). (converts the object to string).

To retrieve from storage you can use:

```js
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(tokenData));
```

Try this:

```js
handleResponse(data:any) {
    let tokenData = {
      token: data.token,
      id: data.id,
      nom: data.nom
    };

    localStorage.setItem('tokenData', JSON.stringify(tokenData);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/livres'); 
}
```